# Copying a range without activating the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to copy a range without activating the sheet that the range is on.

This code works:

```
With Sheet6
  .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "P")).Copy
End With
```

but none of the below lines work:

```
Sheets(6).Range("A1", Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "P")).Copy
Sheet6.Range("A1", Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "P")).Copy

Sheets(6).Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "P")).Copy
Sheet6.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "P")).Copy
```

I'm probably missing something simple here but it seems like a lot of unnecessary code to use `With` for one action.

Comment: In the first you are assigning the sheet parentage to the `Cells(..)` inside the `Range(...` with the `.` in front.  In the others you have removed this.  If you really want the long hand then you will need to put `Sheet6.` in front of every `Cells(`

Comment: In order to use the `.` notation (the last two attempts` you also need to use a `With` block (as in your *working* example). The first two efforts fail for reason @ScottCraner indicates.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I'm finally starting to understand how the `.` works in the code. If you want to turn it into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of odd to have a range from A1 to the P & [Last Row in Column B].  You can accomplish this by finding the last cell in column B and then Offsetting the range to Column A and then extending it up and to the right to P1.  The syntax is a little odd.

```
With Sheet6

  .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1), "P1").Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1")

End With
```

By assigning a variable (lastRow) to = the last row in column B and extend the range from A1 to P & lastrow, the code becomes easier to follow.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheet6

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:P" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1")

End With
```

Comment: I did not know about using `Destination` so that will clear up even more of my code, thanks!  Also I find last row on column B because that column will always have a value present but the way we get the data, column A may not always have a value but is needed later on so it is copied as well.

Comment: This function by Ron de Bruin is better at finding the last row/column/cell.  More reliable.   http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm